# Having Trouble in SImple C Program

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having problem with a simple C program. Even if I enter a year between 1000 and 1999 it still displays invalid year. Please tell me what's happening??

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int year;
c:
    printf("\n\nEnter a Year: ");
    scanf("%d", year);

    if ((year < 1000) || (year > 1999))
    {
        printf("\n\nInvalid Year");
        goto c;
    }
    convert(year);

}
convert(int year)
{
    printf("%d", year);
}
```

Comment: Took me a second to realize that `c:` was not a typo ...

Comment: I would recommend *not* using a `goto` statement.  Instead, use a loop construct.

Comment: +1 for the "everyone says I shouldn't use `goto` but I'll do it anyway` pizazz.

Comment: whenever using `printf()` be sure to add a `\n` at the end of the text you want to show. If you don't you might not see the desired output due to the OS line buffered I/O system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an address to `scanf`, i.e.:

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

Note the ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

in scanf, the other parameters should be pointers
it should be

```
  scanf("%d", &year);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adam Zalcman beat me to it, use 
`scanf("%d", &year)`, and try to avoid goto statements. Replace it with a while loop in the following fashion:

```
main() {
  int year;
  printf("\n\nEnter a Year: ");
  scanf("%d", &year);

  while((year < 1000) || (year > 1999)) {
    printf("\n\nInvalid Year");
    printf("\n\nEnter a Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
  }
}
```

an even better construction would be to use the do{}while() construction, but I'll leave that to you as an exercise :)

Comment: Right now we have loops with checks at the start and loops with checks at the end. We need one with checks in the middle.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes you mean `if(something) break;` ?